# Nested SVG absolute positioning

Tags: css, svg, position, alignment

I currently have the following SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 304 202" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="svg-content" id="container">
  <svg id="drawing" x="0" y="0">
    <rect x="2" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="2" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="102" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="102" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="202" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="202" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="32px" x="1" y="1">
    <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Which produces this:
[image: SVG Result]

No I am trying to position the check mark in the top left corner, (0, 0), but because of the use of `viewBox` it isn't happening. The original size of the icon is 512x512 as it is taken from fontawesome. I can't hard code any offsets as the height of the icon is subject to change dynamically unless I can calculate them. The next SVG was an attempt to position the icon absolutely but has not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewBox` of the squares SVG has width and height of 304 x 202,. So the size of each square is obviously 101 x 101.

So all you need to do is give the "check" SVG a width and height of 101.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="101" height="101" x="1" y="1">
```

And you are done.  Assuming, of course, you wanted it that big.

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 304 202" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="svg-content" id="container">
  <svg id="drawing" x="0" y="0">
    <rect x="2" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="2" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="102" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="102" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="202" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="202" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="101" height="101" x="1" y="1">
    <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

If you don't then adjust the values suitably.  If, for instance, you wanted it to stay at 32, and be centred in the first square.  Then make the width and height 32, and make the `x` and `y`

```
x = y = (101 - 32) / 2
      ~= 36
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 304 202" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="svg-content" id="container">
  <svg id="drawing" x="0" y="0">
    <rect x="2" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="2" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="102" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="102" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="202" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="202" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="32" height="32" x="36" y="36">
    <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the path inside the same SVG and apply a scale transform:

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 304 202" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="svg-content" id="container">
    <rect x="2" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="2" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="102" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="102" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="202" y="1" width="100" height="100" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="202" y="101" width="100" height="100" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <path transform="scale(0.2)" d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
</svg>
```

Or increase the dimension of the `rect` elements and make them as bigger as the icon:

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1539 1026" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="svg-content" id="container">
    <rect x="2" y="1" width="512" height="512" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="2" y="513" width="512" height="512" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="514" y="1" width="512" height="512" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="514" y="513" width="512" height="512" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="1026" y="1" width="512" height="512" fill="#FBFF82" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="1026" y="513" width="512" height="512" fill="#EDB1EE" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <path  d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
</svg>
```